# Qt/Qml load side with text field and opened Virtual Keyboard(vkb)

Tags: qt, qml

Currently, I'm programming a UI-application for an embedded Linux device.
I want to use the vkb inside this application. Sometimes when the vkb is shown, it lays over the item which was calling the vkb, so you can not see the calling item.
To solve this, I want to make an input screen where the user can insert his text. So on the screen should be nothing more than the text field and the keyboard.

The problem is that I don't find a way, how the screen can be loaded with an open keyboard where the keyboard is connected to the text field.

When I load the screen with opened keyboard by using:
`inputPanel.state="visible";`
the vkb is shown but don't write into the text field, it says "input method is not set"

Somebody knows a way to load a screen with opened vkb?

main.c

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

#include <QLocale>
#include <QTranslator>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    qputenv("QT_IM_MODULE", QByteArray("qtvirtualkeyboard"));

#if QT_VERSION < QT_VERSION_CHECK(6, 0, 0)
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
#endif

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QTranslator translator;
    const QStringList uiLanguages = QLocale::system().uiLanguages();
    for (const QString &locale : uiLanguages) {
        const QString baseName = "test_" + QLocale(locale).name();
        if (translator.load(":/i18n/" + baseName)) {
            app.installTranslator(&translator);
            break;
        }
    }

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.VirtualKeyboard 2.4
import QtQuick.VirtualKeyboard.Settings 2.13
import QtQuick.Controls 2.13

Window {
    id: window
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")



    StackView {
        id: pageStack
        z:1
        objectName: "mainStackView"
        initialItem: "qrc:/KeyInputMask.qml"
        anchors.fill: parent
        replaceEnter: Transition {}
        replaceExit: Transition {}
    }

    InputPanel {
        id: inputPanel
        z: 99
        x: 0
        y: window.height
        width: window.width

        states: State {
            name: "visible"
            when: inputPanel.active
            PropertyChanges {
                target: inputPanel
                y: window.height - inputPanel.height
            }
        }
        transitions: Transition {
            from: ""
            to: "visible"
            reversible: true
            ParallelAnimation {
                NumberAnimation {
                    properties: "y"
                    duration: 250
                    easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

KeyInputMask.qml

```
import QtQuick.VirtualKeyboard 2.4
import QtQuick.VirtualKeyboard.Settings 2.13

Item {
    id: keyInsertScreen
    objectName: "KeyInsertScreen"
    signal inputFinished(string editedReturn)

    Rectangle{
        id: bg
        anchors.fill:parent
        color: "grey"
    }


    TextField{
        anchors{
            top: bg.top
            topMargin: (Window.height - inputPanel.height)/2 - height/2
            left: bg.left
            leftMargin: 80
        }
        height: 40
        width: Window.width-(anchors.leftMargin*2)
        wrapMode: Text.Wrap
        font.pixelSize: 18
        focus: true
    }

    Keys.onReleased: {
        if (event.key === Qt.Key_Return || event.key === Qt.Key_Enter){
            parent.inputFinished(inputField.text);
            pageStack.pop();
        }
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        inputPanel.state="visible";
    }

}
```

Comment: A workaround to "_Sometimes when the vkb is shown, it lays over the item which was calling the vkb, so you can not see the calling item._" - When the keyboard is visible, push the item to the top to make it visible. TextInput{
        id: myText;
        y: 400;
        text: "input";
        Connections{
            target: Qt.inputMethod;
            function onVisibleChanged(){
                if(Qt.inputMethod.visible){
                    myText.y = 0
                }
                else{
                    myText.y = 400
                }
            }
        }
    }

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I Alread had tested the solution with scrolling on another slide bevor. The screen is horizontal orientated. For me the scrolling version fits better on an vertically oriented screen.

Answer (score 0):

You should put your textedit, textfield, .. in a Flickable. When the text component get focused, the vkb pop up. If the vkb is over the item, change the contentY of the Flickable.

Qt have gave the example named AutoScroller.qml

[normal state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8MQF.png)
[the vkb popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ttx6D.png)

Here is the code of one of my app:

**VirtualKeyBoard.qml**

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.VirtualKeyboard 2.4
import QtQuick.VirtualKeyboard.Settings 2.2
import QtQml
import QmlGlobalParas

InputPanel {
    id: __inputPanel

    x: 0
    y: QmlGlobalParas.appHeight


    width: QmlGlobalParas.appWidth

    states: [
        State {
            name: "visible"
            when: __inputPanel.active
            PropertyChanges {
                target: __inputPanel
                y: QmlGlobalParas.appHeight - __inputPanel.height - header.height
            }
        },
        // 使用繁易ARM屏测试时，在切换为中文输入法时隐藏键盘，会出现中文输入的选择panel残留在显示器上的问题
        // 增加inVisilble状态，在状态变为不可见时，将输入法切换为英文，以避免该问题 2021.12.08 by lxb
        State {
            name: "inVisible"
            when: !__inputPanel.active

            PropertyChanges {
                target: VirtualKeyboardSettings
                locale: "en_US"
            }
        }
    ]

    transitions: Transition {
        from: ""
        to: "visible"
        reversible: true
        ParallelAnimation {
            NumberAnimation {
                properties: "y"
                duration: 50
                easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad
            }
        }
    }

    AutoScroller {

    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        VirtualKeyboardSettings.activeLocales = ["en_US","zh_CN"]           // 设置允许的语言
        VirtualKeyboardSettings.locale = "en_US"                            // 设置默认的语言
    }


    /*!
    使用绑定方式也可以设置语言
    Binding {
        target: VirtualKeyboardSettings
        property: "activeLocales"
        value: ["en_US", "zh_CN"]
    }
    */


}
```

---

**AutoScroller.qml**

I changed some code: consider the chinese input method. no need to scroll for x axis. 3 Flickable nest ...

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.VirtualKeyboard
import QtQml

Item {

    readonly property int chinesePanelHeight: 40            // 中文输入时，中文选择区域的高度，在style.qml中selectionListHeight定义
    property var innerFlickable
    property var outerFlickable
    property var frameFlickable
    property var inputItem: InputContext.priv.inputItem
    property string inputLocal: InputContext.locale

    readonly property int __defaultScrollMarginVertical: 20

    onInputItemChanged: {        
        innerFlickable = null
        outerFlickable = null
        frameFlickable = null
//        if (!Qt.inputMethod.visible)
        {
            if (inputItem) {
                var parent_ = inputItem.parent
                while (parent_) {
                    if (parent_.maximumFlickVelocity) {
                        if (outerFlickable) {
                            outerFlickable = null
                            innerFlickable = null
                            frameFlickable = parent_
                            break
                        } else if (innerFlickable) {
                            innerFlickable = null
                            outerFlickable = parent_
                        } else {
                            innerFlickable = parent_
                        }
                    }
                    parent_ = parent_.parent
                }
                delayedLoading.restart()
            }
        }
    }

    function ensureVisible(flickable) {

        if (flickable && Qt.inputMethod.visible && inputItem && flickable.visible && flickable.interactive) {

            var verticallyFlickable = (flickable.flickableDirection === Flickable.HorizontalAndVerticalFlick || flickable.flickableDirection === Flickable.VerticalFlick
                                       || (flickable.flickableDirection === Flickable.AutoFlickDirection && flickable.contentHeight > flickable.height))

            /* 水平不需要滚动，屏蔽这部分代码
            var horizontallyFlickable = (flickable.flickableDirection === Flickable.HorizontalAndVerticalFlick || flickable.flickableDirection === Flickable.HorizontalFlick
                                         || (flickable.flickableDirection === Flickable.AutoFlickDirection && flickable.contentWidth > flickable.width))

            if ((!verticallyFlickable && !horizontallyFlickable) || !inputItem.hasOwnProperty("cursorRectangle"))
                return
            */

            if ((!verticallyFlickable) || !inputItem.hasOwnProperty("cursorRectangle"))
                return

            var cursorRectangle = flickable.contentItem.mapFromItem(inputItem, inputItem.cursorRectangle.x, inputItem.cursorRectangle.y)

            var oldContentY = flickable.contentY
            if (verticallyFlickable) {
                var scrollMarginVertical = (flickable && flickable.scrollMarginVertical) ? flickable.scrollMarginVertical : __defaultScrollMarginVertical

                if (flickable.contentY >= cursorRectangle.y  - scrollMarginVertical)
                {
                    flickable.contentY = Math.max(0, cursorRectangle.y  - scrollMarginVertical)
                }
                else if (flickable.contentY + flickable.height <= cursorRectangle.y  + inputItem.cursorRectangle.height + scrollMarginVertical)
                {
                    flickable.contentY = Math.max(flickable.contentHeight - flickable.height, cursorRectangle.y + inputItem.cursorRectangle.height - flickable.height + scrollMarginVertical)
                }
            }
            /* 水平不需要滚动，屏蔽这部分代码
            if (horizontallyFlickable) {
                var scrollMarginHorizontal = (flickable && flickable.scrollMarginHorizontal) ? flickable.scrollMarginHorizontal : 10
                if (flickable.contentX >= cursorRectangle.x - scrollMarginHorizontal)
                    flickable.contentX = Math.max(0, cursorRectangle.x - scrollMarginHorizontal)
                else if (flickable.contentX + flickable.width <= cursorRectangle.x + inputItem.cursorRectangle.width + scrollMarginHorizontal)
                    flickable.contentX = Math.min(flickable.contentWidth - flickable.width, cursorRectangle.x + inputItem.cursorRectangle.width - flickable.width + scrollMarginHorizontal)
            }
            */
        }
    }

    function adjectVisible(flickable) {
        if (flickable && flickable.contentY > 0)
        {
            if ("zh_CN" === inputLocal)
            {
                flickable.contentY += chinesePanelHeight
            }
            else
            {
                if (flickable.contentY >= chinesePanelHeight)
                {
                    flickable.contentY -= chinesePanelHeight
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Timer {
        id: delayedLoading
        interval: 100
        onTriggered: {
            ensureVisible(innerFlickable)
            ensureVisible(outerFlickable)
            ensureVisible(frameFlickable)
        }
    }

    /* 如果输入法切换为中文，且内部高度 */
    onInputLocalChanged: {
        adjectVisible(frameFlickable)
        adjectVisible(outerFlickable)
        adjectVisible(innerFlickable)
    }

    Connections {
        ignoreUnknownSignals: true
        target: Qt.inputMethod

        function onAnimatingChanged() {
            if (inputItem && !Qt.inputMethod.animating)
            {
                delayedLoading.restart()
            }
        }
        function onKeyboardRectangleChanged() {
            if (inputItem)
            {
                delayedLoading.restart()
            }
        }
        function onCursorRectangleChanged() {
            if (inputItem && inputItem.activeFocus && !Qt.inputMethod.visible)
            {
                delayedLoading.restart()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Comment: Thank you, for your solution to scroll the calling item in the visible area, I tested a similar solution before. With a horizontal orientated screen, it feels a little confusing when the page scroll automatically up. So I try to find a solution to call a side with an opened vkb.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to "pin" what you're currently inputting. Mind that its a bit janky but was made quickly to give an example.

```
InputPanel {
    id: vkbPanel
    z: 99
    x: 0
    y: window.height
    width: window.width

    states: State {
        name: "visible"
        when: vkbPanel.active
        PropertyChanges {
            target: vkbPanel
            y: window.height - vkbPanel.height
        }
    }
    transitions: Transition {
        from: ""
        to: "visible"
        reversible: true
        ParallelAnimation {
            NumberAnimation {
                properties: "y"
                duration: 250
                easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad
            }
        }
    }

    TextInput{
        id: inputSuperclass
        inputMethodHints: Qt.ImhFormattedNumbersOnly
        focus: Qt.inputMethod.visible // <---!!! This line is very important
    }
    Label{
        text: inputSuperclass.text
        anchors{
            bottom: vkbPanel.top
            horizontalCenter: vkbPanel.horizontalCenter
        }
        color: '#ffffff'
    }
}
```

Make sure you create all kinds of text inputs to suit your needs - i've got only "ImhFormattedNumbersOnly" implemented. So if you need other input methods, you'll need to copy and paste this solution but with a different inputMethodHint.